# Tasklist / Taskkill Logon Failure

Tags: authentication, passwords, command-prompt, taskkill, tasklist

I am trying the list tasks on a Win10 PC from a Win7 PC so I can create a batch script to kill that process.

the following is the code i have typed in command prompt (running in administrator mode)

> tasklist /s remotepc /u remotepc\user /p password

This keeps returning the error

> ERROR: Logon Failure: unknown username or bad password

I've triple checked the username password and computer name and they are all correct.
I've tried dropping the computer/domain name for the /U command but that did not work.

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of suggestions to try: 1 - Try the IP address of the remote machine rather than `remotepc`; 2 - Try omitting `remotepc` when specifying the user parameter.

Comment: I get the same error if I use the IP address rather than the PC name

Comment: What if you try `/u user` instead of `/u remotepc\user`?

Comment: Sorry nm, I see you said you tried that in your question.

Comment: I'd be curious if you can `net use \\remotepc\ipc$ /user:remotepc\user password`.

Comment: That command was completed successfully

Comment: So now can you simply `tasklist /s remotepc`?

Comment: In addition, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/529404) may be helpful.

Comment: if I try 'tasklist /s remotepc' i am prompted for the password of my useraccount on the computer i am currently using.
i tried adding the '/u and /p' parameters but that returned the unkown user or bad password error

Comment: If that other answer didn't help, I'd recommend going to Google for "fix remote wmi authentication" - it will turn up a lot of things that you can try to try to get WMI authentication to work.

Comment: I have downloaded PStools as suggested in the  link.
I can get `pslist`to work using there instructions but not pskill

Comment: PSTools suite is excellent.  What is the error from `pskill`?